# preventing all subdirectory listing by redirecting

Tags: html, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to prevent all subdirectory listings and redirect to index page instead.

Folder structure is the following:

/images

/images/folder1

/images/folder2

/images/folder3

/images/folder4

etc.

The number of folders is not predefined. I want to place .htaccess file in /images folder to provent /images/folder1, /images/folder2 etc. listing in browser.

I have not found the sollution. I have just found how to prevent listing using

`Options -Indexes`,

but no idea how to redirect to homepage (for all subfolders).

When it was predefined number of folders, I simply put index.html with redirection inside those, but now the number of folders is dynamic.

EDIT:
I have already  looked into google searching something like "RewriteRule example redirect all subfoldres to homepage" and similar.
For example:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder1.*$ http://example.com/folder2/ [R=301,L]
```

However, I have not found the solution with dynamic folder (if I do not know the exact name of folder, but I need to take all subfolders).
As I am new to htaccess writing it seems tricky for me.

Comment: Look into `mod_rewrite`, and its `RewriteRule` directive. You will find lots of examples online.

Comment: I have already looked into google, but have not found anything that works for all subfolders (with not predefined number of subfolders and not predefined names of subfolders - the names can be timestamps or similar).

Comment: Ah, OK. Always include attempted solutions in your question, so people can know what you've tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work for you in `images/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.+$ / [R=301,L]
```

It redirect every request from images folder which is for any directory but not for a file to your home page `/`

Answer (score -1):

Modify your .htaccess file to prevent indexing like this:

```
Options -Indexes
```

The folders won't be shown.